# May I change the order of the tags?

Tags: tags

I have a list of all tag. I want set a order for them, form example, as order of slug?
Here is the code for get all tags.

```
<?php
$tags = get_tags();
foreach ( $tags as $tag ) {
    $tag_link = get_tag_link( $tag->term_id);
    $html .= "<a href='{$tag_link}' title='{$tag->name}' class='{$tag->slug}'>";
    $html .= "{$tag->name}</a>";
}
echo $html;
?>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll have to specify the `order` and the `orderby` parameters within `get_tags()`. If you want an ascending order by slug you can update youre code snippet this way:

```
$tags = get_tags( 'order=ASC&orderby=slug' );
```

There are also a lot of other parameter as you can see in the codex:
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_tags#Parameters